# WSO2 - Restricting the Access to Management Console

Tags: console, wso2

I have been trying to restrict the access to the WSO2 Console access of my application to the public. Configuration to access should be a port based or IP based. I have tried different techniques to restrict the access of WSO2 Console to the public except in my work environment.

Example:

I have used "class":"org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter" and added my IP address as a parameter to this class in order to enable the restriction and also used ||"/> in **content.xml** this but nothing works as per my expectation.

I have spent several hours on this issue to achieve the solution but it wasn't working as per the requirement.

Hopefully someone here has done something similar can help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: Have you considered using a firewall instead to lock down access to the server on certain ports?

Comment: @Riverchimp, i can do that but that's not the exact solution i need why because some times i need to restrict based on the IP address also like enabling to some people/company so it should be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I want to restrict access to the Mgt Console to just localhost, but you should be able to add your additional ip addresses to this 'localhost only' solution.

WSO2 Identity Server 6.0

Add to {WSO2IS_HOME}\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>localhost|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/carbon/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Bonus: Control adding the above by setting a deployment.toml property

Add deployment.toml property:

```
[server]
...
mgt_console_localhost_only=true
```

Copy {WSO2IS_HOME}\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon\WEB-INF\web.xml
to: {WSO2IS_HOME}\repository\resources\conf\templates\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon\WEB-INF\web.xml.j2

Add to web.xml.j2:

```
{% if server.mgt_console_localhost_only is sameas true %}
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allow</param-name>
            <param-value>localhost|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/carbon/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
{% endif %}
```